# How to select hCaptcha box with Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, hcaptcha

I need some help with my website register bot that uses Python and Selenium. I can input all the information the signup needs but I can't find a way to solve the hCaptcha on the page. I have tried answers that are already on here but none work so if anyone has a solution please reply with it.

Website: https://www.brick-hill.com/register

Comment: Solve or select?

Comment: If you are trying to select it please provide the markup instead of the link.

Comment: If the hCaptcha is any good at detecting that you are a human, it should not be easily doable by a bot. You may need to build in a pause there where you have a human sign in. Or, if it's a site you are testing for your company, you may need a test system where this is left out.

Comment: or you would need a test key set up on the test system (only) to bypass the hcaptcha. See https://docs.hcaptcha.com/. But that would only be if you work for brick-hill